# After opening port 443 in windows firewall as inbound rule, I cannot see it when I run 'netstat -an'

Tags: windows, port, tcp, netstat

As an inbound rule on Windows 10 firewall, I added port 443 as TCP connection allowing all types of connections. However, I cannot see it when I run 'netstat -an'. How can I get it so that I see my localhost 443 listening?

The output of 'netstat -an' is below

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:623            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2179           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2701           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5040           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8732           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:9031           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:9999           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:16992          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49664          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49665          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49666          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49667          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49668          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49671          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49672          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49673          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49676          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    100.67.20.86:139       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51041     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51055     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51063     198.161.14.25:80       CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51064     198.161.14.25:80       CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51065     198.161.14.25:80       CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51066     198.161.14.26:1328     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51067     198.161.14.26:1328     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51068     198.161.14.26:1328     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51071     198.161.14.26:1328     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51084     198.161.14.26:1328     CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51100     198.161.14.25:8080     CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51101     198.161.14.25:8080     CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51102     198.161.14.25:8080     CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51103     198.161.14.25:8080     CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51104     198.161.14.25:8080     CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51105     198.161.14.25:8080     CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51106     198.161.14.25:8080     CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51107     198.161.14.25:8080     CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51109     198.161.14.25:8080     CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51110     198.161.14.25:8080     CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51142     198.161.14.26:1328     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51143     198.161.14.26:1328     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51144     198.161.14.26:1328     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51145     198.161.14.26:1328     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51146     198.161.14.25:8080     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51147     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51148     198.161.14.26:1328     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51150     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51151     198.161.14.26:1328     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51153     198.161.14.26:1328     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51154     198.161.14.25:8080     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51155     198.161.14.26:1328     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51156     198.161.14.26:1328     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51157     198.161.14.26:1328     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51160     198.161.14.26:1328     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51161     198.161.14.26:1328     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51162     198.161.14.26:1328     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51167     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51168     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51169     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51173     198.161.14.26:1328     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51174     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51177     198.161.14.25:8080     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51178     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51179     198.161.14.26:1328     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51180     198.161.14.25:8080     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51181     198.161.14.26:1328     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51182     198.161.14.26:1328     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51185     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51186     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51187     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51188     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51189     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51190     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51191     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51192     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51193     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51194     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51195     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51196     100.66.133.16:80       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51197     100.66.133.16:80       TIME_WAIT
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51688     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51822     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51928     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:51959     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:52090     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:52126     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:52270     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:52291     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:52329     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:52335     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:52391     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:52432     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:52459     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:52481     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:52503     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:52574     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:52594     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:53670     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:53707     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:54638     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:54661     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:54726     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:54758     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:54785     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:54886     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:54960     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:54973     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:55240     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:59638     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:59648     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:59752     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:59866     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:59962     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:59997     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:60132     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:60206     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:60239     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:60253     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:60266     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:61879     142.174.118.19:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:61986     142.174.118.19:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:62008     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:62512     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:62547     198.161.14.25:8080     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    100.67.20.86:62725     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:63003     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    100.67.20.86:63040     198.161.14.26:1328     FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    127.0.0.1:31000        127.0.0.1:32000        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:32000        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:32000        127.0.0.1:31000        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50261        127.0.0.1:50262        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50262        127.0.0.1:50261        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50263        127.0.0.1:50264        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50264        127.0.0.1:50263        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50272        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50273        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50401        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54034        127.0.0.1:62522        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62522        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62522        127.0.0.1:54034        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    172.17.124.193:139     0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.0.15:139       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.0.15:62439     66.203.207.35:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.56.1:139       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:623               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:2179              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:2701              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:3389              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:5357              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:8732              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:9031              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:9999              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:16992             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49664             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49665             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49666             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49667             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49668             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49671             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49672             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49673             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49676             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:61868            [::1]:61870            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:61870            [::1]:61868            ESTABLISHED
  UDP    0.0.0.0:53             *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:123            *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3389           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5050           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:51673          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:52306          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:56208          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:56209          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:61402          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:61403          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:61404          *:*
  UDP    100.67.20.86:137       *:*
  UDP    100.67.20.86:138       *:*
  UDP    100.67.20.86:1900      *:*
  UDP    100.67.20.86:2177      *:*
  UDP    100.67.20.86:61495     *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:54995        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:55184        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:55506        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:56283        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:61498        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:62996        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:64439        *:*
  UDP    172.17.124.193:67      *:*
  UDP    172.17.124.193:68      *:*
  UDP    172.17.124.193:137     *:*
  UDP    172.17.124.193:138     *:*
  UDP    172.17.124.193:1900    *:*
  UDP    172.17.124.193:2177    *:*
  UDP    172.17.124.193:61499   *:*
  UDP    192.168.0.15:137       *:*
  UDP    192.168.0.15:138       *:*
  UDP    192.168.0.15:1900      *:*
  UDP    192.168.0.15:2177      *:*
  UDP    192.168.0.15:61497     *:*
  UDP    192.168.56.1:137       *:*
  UDP    192.168.56.1:138       *:*
  UDP    192.168.56.1:1900      *:*
  UDP    192.168.56.1:2177      *:*
  UDP    192.168.56.1:61496     *:*
  UDP    [::]:123               *:*
  UDP    [::]:3389              *:*
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*
  UDP    [::]:51674             *:*
  UDP    [::]:56210             *:*
  UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*
  UDP    [::1]:61494            *:*
```

Comment: You've openened a port but there's no process listening at that port. You've created a hole in your firewall but there's no service to handle traffic coming through that port.

Comment: @StarCat I see. Essentially, I want to run the equivalent of ":lsof -n -P -i:443" on Windows and see "443 (ESTABLISHED). But you're saying that I actually need a service to handle traffic through that port.

Comment: AFAIK `lsof -n -P -i:443` will also only list sockets connected to listening processes and will not detect ports that are just open with nothing listening.  It will only show (ESTABLISHED) when there’s a client connected. What you need is a port scanner (I think).

Comment: Have you tried telnet to see if the connnection can succeed on port 443.